# Problems with accuracy.score sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, error-handling

I am learning python and trying myself out at mashine learning. I am reproducing a super simple example - based on the infamous iris dataset. Here it goes:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .5)

from sklearn import tree
nordan_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

nordan_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tree3.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
NameError: name 'predictions' is not defined
```

I don't get it. As far as I understand, `predictions` is the vector containing all the predictions produced with  `DecisionTreeClassifier`? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined the variable `predictions` anywhere. You will need to get them from your classifier somehow. You have fit your `nordan_tree` on your training data, now you can use the fitted `nordan_tree` to generate the predictions, for example like this:

```
predictions = nordan_tree.predict(X_test)
```

Then your line of:

```
print(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks alot! That answers my questions perfectly. I thought - somehow - that sklearn's tree-clf stores the predictions in `predictions` by default.

Comment: It has never seen your test set yet so it wouldn't know what to predict on, and packages generally do not put anything in global variables but return their values via the functions calls (in this case the predict function of your classifier object)

Comment: I am a frequent stata user and python is totally new to me. Your answer helps me a great deal. Thank you!  Now I only need to understand how to print the decision tree... slowly...but steady.

Comment: The sklearn package has terrific documentation and a lot of examples, make sure to look at those!

Answer (score 2):

Use the below instructions as it was worked for me

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

predictions = nordan_tree.predict(X_test)

print(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
```